# Magento admin grid sending data from Action to Controller

Tags: magento, grid, action, adminhtml

I'm trying to write a custom action to run off of an admin grid that I have built. Is it possible to send a value from a column in the grid to the controller via either get or post?

I've tried googling, but I cannot find a proper explanation for this anywhere. A link to an explanation of the column settings ('getter', 'type' etc.) would also be useful if this is available.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this code to your Grid.php:

```
        $this->addColumn('action',
            array(
            'header'    =>  Mage::helper('yourmodulename')->__('Action'),
            'width'     => '100',
            'type'      => 'action',
            'getter'    => 'getId',
            'actions'   => array(
                    array(
                            'caption'   => Mage::helper('yourmodulename')->__('Edit'),
                            'url'       => array('base'=> '*/*/edit'),
                            'field'     => 'id'
                    )
            ),
            'filter'    => false,
            'sortable'  => false,
            'index'     => 'stores',
            'is_system' => true,
    ));
```

That will build an "Edit" URL with the Id of the selected row as part of the URL.  It will look something like `<frontname>/<controllername>/edit/id/<value>` where `value` is returned by the getter `getId()`.

The getter field will execute any of the standard Magento magic getters, ie any attribute is gettable.  So you could have `getName` or `getProductUrl` or `getIsLeftHanded` if you wanted and your controller can parse the attribute.

The controller can then retrieve that passed value using `Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('attributename');`

In terms of documentation/tutorials, have a read of [this article](http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_controllers) on the website of @AlanStorm as it might help.

HTH,
JD

Comment: Thanks for your help, that's pretty much all I needed to know. I didn't realise you could use 'getter' to pick pretty much any attribute.

Comment: The getter is new to me as well, but exactly what I needed.

Comment: What if I want to get more than one getter means What if I want to pass multi parameter in URL which can't be access be using  Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('attributename')

Comment: Should I use getter=>array('attribute1',attribute2);